# Shiny server inside Docker container reverse proxied with nginx will not follow 301 redirects

Tags: r, nginx, amazon-ec2, docker, shiny-server

There are 3 ingredients to this issue:

1. **Docker container**: I have a Docker container that is deployed on an EC2 instance. More specifically, I have the [`rocker/shiny`](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/shiny/) image, which I have run using:

   ```
   sudo docker run -d -v /home/ubuntu/projects/shiny_example:/srv/shiny-server -p 3838:3838 rocker/shiny
   ```
2. **Shiny server**: The standard Shiny server configuration file is untouched, and is set up to serve everything in the `/srv/shiny-server` folder on port 3838, and the contents of my local `~/projects/shiny_example` are mapped to the container's `/srv/shiny-server/`.

   In my local `~/projects/shiny_example`, I have cloned a random Shiny app:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/rstudio/shiny_example
   ```
3. **nginx**: I have set up `nginx` as a reverse proxy and [here](https://gist.github.com/tchakravarty/094578cec606653653882cdaec4501ad) are the contents of the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in its entirety.

---

The issue is that with this setup, when I try to retrieve `http://<ip-address>/shiny/shiny_example`, I get a 404. The main clue I have as to what might be wrong is that when I do a:

```
 wget http://localhost:3838/shiny_example
```

from the command line on my EC2 instance, I get:

> --2016-06-13 11:05:08--  http://localhost:3838/shiny_example 
>   Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
>
> Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:3838... connected.
>
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... **301 Moved Permanently**
>
> **Location: /shiny_example/ [following]**
>
> --2016-06-13 11:05:08--  http://localhost:3838/shiny_example/
>
> Reusing existing connection to localhost:3838.
>
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
>
> Length: 3136 (3.1K) [text/html]
>
> Saving to: ‘shiny_example.3’
>
> 100%[==============================================================================================================================>] 3,136       --.-K/s   in 0.04s
>
> 2016-06-13 11:05:09 (79.6 KB/s) - ‘shiny_example.3’ saved [3136/3136]

where the **emphasis is mine**.

I think that my nginx configuration does not account for the fact that when requesting a Docker mapped port, there is a 301 redirect. I think that the solution involves [`proxy_next_upstream`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_next_upstream), but I would appreciate some help in trying to set this up in my context.

I also think that this question can be shorn of the Docker context, but it would be nice to understand how to prevent a 301 redirect when requesting a resource from Shiny server that is in a Docker container, and whether this behavior is expected.

Comment: Are you doing your outside connection to `http://<ip-address>/shiny/shiny_example` or `http://<ip-address>:3838/shiny/shiny_example/`? It would help is you showed the failing wget command too. Note that the redirect is just adding a trailing slash to your url, that's not Docker doing the 301.

Comment: @BMitch nginx is listening on 80 and reverse proxying `localhost:3838`. Also note that the `wget` is not failing but is handling the 301 gracefully.

Comment: @BMitch So, just to be explicit, I am doing my outside connection to `http://<ip-address>/shiny/shiny_example/`. And the output of the `wget` is included in the question.

Comment: Correct, you have only shown us things working successfully, but suggested there are other things that are broken. It would help if you included the failure and how you've narrowed it down to nginx not handling the 301 vs any other possible issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with anything. Basically, one of the lines in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` was `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*`, which was pulling in the default file for enabled sites, which has the following lines:

```
 server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }
```

which was overwriting my listen directives for port 80 and for location `/`. Commenting out the include directive for the default conf file for enabled sites in the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file resolved all issues for me.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure without more output, but suspect your error is in your proxy_redirect line:

```
    location /shiny/ {
      rewrite ^/shiny/(.*)$ /$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3838;
      proxy_redirect http://localhost:3838/ $scheme://$host/shiny_example;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
      proxy_read_timeout 20d;
    }
```

Try changing that to:

```
    location /shiny/ {
      rewrite ^/shiny/(.*)$ /$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3838;
      proxy_redirect http://localhost:3838/ $scheme://$host/shiny/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
      proxy_read_timeout 20d;
    }
```

The reason for that is when the 301 header comes back from "http://localhost:3838" to add the trailing slash, it gets rewritten to "http://localhost/shiny_example" which doesn't exist in your nginx config, plus it may also remove a slash from the path. This means the 301 from "http://localhost:3838/shiny_example" to "http://localhost:3838/shiny_example/" would get rewritten to to "http://localhost/shiny_exampleshiny_example/", at which point you get a 404.

Comment: Thanks for your answer BMitch. I understand your line of reasoning. However, I feel that the reason that the `http_redirect` line is written the way that it is, is that the server implements websockets and the `scheme` (i.e. `ws:`) is important to handle. [Here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213733868-Running-Shiny-Server-with-a-Proxy) is a reference for this.

Comment: Also, can you please list the things that you want me to try and include the output of? It is not clear to me from your comment.

Comment: The output I'm looking for is a failing wget line from http://localhost/shiny/shiny_example. You've said you're seeing a 404 that you believe is related to the 301, but haven't provided any output, logs, or other details on that. I've updated the answer to include the $scheme redirect, from the URL provided, I did not see the $host/shiny_example, only $host/shiny/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant but I have a minimal example here: https://github.com/mRcSchwering/butterbirne

A service `shinyserver` (which is based on `rocker/shiny`) is started with a service `webserver` (based on `nginx:latest`):

```
version: '2'

services:

  shinyserver:
    build: shinyserver/

  webserver:
    build: webserver/
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

I configured the ngin, so that it would redirect directly to the shiny server root. In my case I added the app (called `myapp` here) as the root  of shinyserver (so no `/myapp` is needed). This is the whole `nginx.conf`:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;


    # apparently this is needed for shiny server
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
      }

    # proxy shinyserver
    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://shinyserver:3838;
          proxy_redirect http://shinyserver:3838/ $scheme://$host/;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
          proxy_read_timeout 20d;
          proxy_buffering off;
        }
    }
}
```